# error when installing django in virtualenv with dockerfile

Tags: python, django, docker

```
FROM webdevops/base:ubuntu-16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-  recommends \ 
    apache2 \
    openssh-client \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-venv \
    python3-psycopg2 \
    python3-pip \
    pyflakes3 \
    pylint3 \
    pep8 \
    pep257 \
    postgresql-client \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/hotels-project
RUN cd /var/www/html/hotels-project/ \
   && python3 -m venv hotels-venv \
   && /bin/bash -c "source hotels-venv/bin/activate" 

RUN pip install 'django<2.0'
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install psycopg2
```

show message:

> ERROR: Service 'apache-python' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh
>   -c pip install 'django<2.0'' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You should probably use `pip3` since that's what you're installing...

Comment: Just a comment. One thing I don't understand here. If you are using Docker why to install all the stuff in one container? Would it not be better to create compose file where you have Apache container + Python container for Django + Postgresql container. This way you end up configuring everything deployment ready from the get-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your docker file.

- Using `pip` instead of `pip3`
- Activating `virtualenv` in one step and running commands in another step

In Dockerfile for every `RUN` step, you get a fresh terminal. So any `source` command you executed in previous `RUN` statement is no more active.

So your code should be something like this

```
RUN cd /var/www/html/hotels-project/ \
   && python3 -m venv hotels-venv \
   && /bin/bash -c "source hotels-venv/bin/activate" \
   && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

And `requirements.txt` should have below content

```
django<2.0
requests==X.XX
psycopg2==y.yy
```

That's how you should do it

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know was so important to keep the commands in one "RUN" because a fresh terminal is created otherwise. I didn't know that, thanks !